# Passing single object vs passing multiple parameters WebAPI2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on WepApi2 where I am implementing an advanced search function. I have three options right now There are more than 10 parameters with some pagination parameters.

1) To pass an object as a parameter which will have all the required filters.

2) Pass about 10-12 parameters.

3) Extension of approach 1. I will convert an object to the query string and then Query string back to object. Problem with this is that I will not have default Get method which can return all the result. I could, however, check if the query string is null and call that method.

Which of them should I choose?. In the first one, I will have to do boxing and unboxing as HttpClient Get request doesn't support Body.

In the second one, I will have to change two to three place even if one parameter is added as I am using Three-tier architecture.

**Code For First Approach**

```
public class GeneralSearchViewModel
{
    public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public bool CalculateTotal { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
public class SomeAdvanceFilterClass : GeneralSearchViewModel
{
    public Guid Dummy { get; set; }
    public string DummyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string DummyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string DummyProperty4 { get; set; }
    public string DummyProperty5 { get; set; }
    public string DummyProperty6 { get; set; }
}
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    public SearchResultModel<DummyModel> Get(SomeAdvanceFilterClass filter)
    {
        Logic logic = new Logic();
        return logic.GetResult(filters);
    }
}
```

*Don't know how to call it as HttpClient Doesn't support Get Request with body parameters. Even if it some how does its not recommended because of caching issues and some other.*

**Second Approach**

```
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    public SearchResultModel<DummyModel> Get(int RecordsPerPage,bool CalculateTotal,int CurrentPage,Guid Dummy,string DummyProperty2....)
    {
        Logic logic = new Logic();
        return logic.GetResult(RecordsPerPage,CalculateTotal,CurrentPage,Dummy...);
    }
}
```

*It would require some changes in route configuration or I would need to use default parameter. Moreover change in one parameter requires changes in all layers*

All the approaches seem to have some big issues. Any good recommendation. I am not using.NETCORE so cant use Get request with the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FromUri] attribute to work with first approach.

```
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
   public SearchResultModel<DummyModel> Get([FromUri]SomeAdvanceFilterClass filter)
   {
     Logic logic = new Logic();
     return logic.GetResult(filters);
   }
}
```

In this case values from URI should be mapped to your class.

Comment: How to send an object using HttpClient with a get request?

Comment: @SafiMustafa it's direct mapping from parameter name to class property name in case of simple class as in example. So it should be like:
/api/dummy?Dummy=b94a3f1b-15cd-4feb-ac34-bd58bc1c3c2b&DummyProperty2=somedata

Comment: Yes I had to convert object into query string. So I wrote an function to convert any object to query string.